# Select Mysql Query issue to get data from two tables

Tags: mysql

I have Two Table.

```
1.  tbl_courier (It has 2 Columns)

    cons_no, orignal_awb
    0906018  109118084926
    0906018  109118085755
    0906019  109118086800
    etc

2. tbl_awb (it has 4 columns)

    id    awb_no         courier_id   active`
    35    109118084926        8         y
    36    109118085755        8         y
    37    109118086800        8         y
    38    109118086900        9         y
    39    109118086950        9         y
```

## I need this list.

```
cons_no, orignal_awb   courier_id
0906018  109118084926      8
0906018  109118085755      8
0906019  109118086800      9
```

### I try this one

```
Select t.cons_no, t.orignal_awb, a.awb_no, a.courier_id
From tbl_courier t
JOIN awb a on t.orignal_awb = a.awb_no
```

### which give me just this.

```
cons_no    orignal_awb     awb_no         courier_id
0906018    109118084926    109118084926   8
```

Comment: From what I could understand from the table structure, original_awb and awb_no are some sort of foreign key fields, you are getting only one row in your query because it's the only one that matches the join condition in the ON clause

Comment: query looks ok, but your data seems to not support your wishes...

Comment: which datatype are the column  orignal_awb and awb_no          ??

Comment: also in the select you are referencing an awb table that doesn't exist in the given structure

Comment: can you do a `describe tbl_courier` and  `describe tbl_awb` ?

Answer (score 2):

Could be your values contains some hidden char as space  try trim the values for join

```
Select t.cons_no, t.orignal_awb, a.awb_no, a.courier_id
From tbl_courier t
INNER JOIN awb a on trim(t.orignal_awb) = trim(a.awb_no)
```

Comment: When I use this Query

Select t.cons_no, t.orignal_awb, a.awb_no, a.courier_id 
From tbl_courier t 
LEFT JOIN awb a on t.orignal_awb = a.awb_no

Comment: I get the following Result.
-------------------------------------------------
cons_no   orignal_awb    awb_no      courier_id
0906019   109118344346   NULL          NULL
0906019   1319418102705  NULL          NULL
0906019   43275512350    NULL          NULL
0906019   789525214389   NULL          NULL
0906018   109118085755   NULL          NULL
0906018   109118084926   109118084926   8

Comment: Whereas I want Like This:
cons_no   orignal_awb    awb_no        courier_id
0906019   109118344346   109118344346      15
0906019   1319418102705  1319418102705     15
0906019   43275512350    43275512350       15
0906019   789525214389   789525214389      15
0906018   109118085755   109118085755       8
0906018   109118084926   109118084926       8

Comment: dont post code or result as comment  .. update your question  adding info in question area...  .. is impossible understand you last command ..

Comment: Anyway if you want the result you have in your question you must use inner join  not left  join  ..

Comment: Left join are for not matching values  .. inner join only for matching values

Answer (score 0):

When I use this query

Select t.cons_no, t.orignal_awb, a.awb_no, a.courier_id 
From tbl_courier t 
LEFT JOIN awb a on t.orignal_awb = a.awb_no

```
I get the following Result.
-------------------------------------------------
cons_no   orignal_awb    awb_no      courier_id
0906019   109118344346   NULL          NULL
0906019   1319418102705  NULL          NULL
0906019   43275512350    NULL          NULL
0906019   789525214389   NULL          NULL
0906018   109118085755   NULL          NULL
0906018   109118084926   109118084926   8
```

Whereas I want Like This:

```
cons_no   orignal_awb    awb_no        courier_id
0906019   109118344346   109118344346      15
0906019   1319418102705  1319418102705     15
0906019   43275512350    43275512350       15
0906019   789525214389   789525214389      15
0906018   109118085755   109118085755       8
0906018   109118084926   109118084926       8
```

Comment: this is not the sample you provide in question  .. changing the question make all diificult to understand  ... and is not fair ..